# Android SDK API/Feature Breakdown?

Tags: android

Is there anyway I can look at "what's new"/release notes in any of the releases for the Android SDK?

Specifically new API's that have been added per version. For example DreamService is only available in API 17 and up.

Comment: both of these answers are correct. But I have to give it up to Pleerock because the change logs are way more prettier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see official site. Go to http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html . You can choose specific API on the left panel

Answer (score 3):

Each API level has a changes page, which is like a summary, as well as a full changes report.

For example, the Android 4.2 "changes page" can be found here: [**Android 4.2 APIs**](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html) *(Note: You can navigate all versions by using the menu on the left.)*

And the full changes report can be found here: [**Android API Differences Report**](http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/17/changes.html) *(Note: Not as easy to navigate; changing the "17" in the URL is the easiest way to explore previous API versions.)*